# Using Android PresetReverb on AudioTrack

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble enabling reverb on an audio track in my Android app. Does anyone actually know how this works? I've been looking all over the place but the documentation is pretty bad and contradicts itself at multiple points. I've seen old posts about this, but none of them contain any actual answers. Only thing I know so far is that instantiating an effect with session ID 0 and then applying to the audio track is deprecated (well, according to [AudioEffect docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect#summary), but not [PresetReverb docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/PresetReverb#PresetReverb(int,%20int))). Here is my code:

```
PresetReverb reverb = new PresetReverb(1, audioTrack.getAudioSessionId());
reverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEHALL);
reverb.setEnabled(true);
audioTrack.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
```

Why is it not applying any reverb?

The logged output from `setEnabled(true)` is 0, [supposedly meaning success](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect#SUCCESS).

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't think I did

Comment: Okay, looks like, I will have to ditch it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deprecation of creating effects with audiosession 0 is specifically for *insert* effects. `PresetReverb` is an *auxiliary* effect, and its documentation says this:

> As the PresetReverb is an auxiliary effect it is recommended to instantiate it on audio session 0 and to attach it to the MediaPLayer auxiliary output.

In your case you have an `AudioTrack` rather than a `MediaPlayer`, but it's the same thing. So it seems to me like you should be doing something like this instead:

```
PresetReverb reverb = new PresetReverb(1, 0);
reverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEHALL);
reverb.setEnabled(true);
audioTrack.attachAuxEffect(reverb.getId());
audioTrack.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
```

(I'm not sure about the correct order of these calls, as I haven't tested this myself)

Comment: That clarifies a couple of things, thank you for the answer. I've already tried this approach and sadly ended up with an error which I haven't been able to find much info about. This might fit better in a new post, but every time I try to instantiate the reverb with session id 0 i get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize effect engine for type: 47382d60-ddd8-11db-bf3a-0002a5d5c51b Error: -3`. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really. I think -3 is `ERROR_NO_INIT`, but why you'd get that I don't know. I assume your app has the `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission(?).

Comment: Yes, that permission is configured. Well I will do some more digging and maybe post this as a new question with a more detailed explanation. Thanks for your help!